# How to apply the "Interactable" component without changing default color?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to use `Interactable` component of `Mixed Reality Toolkit`. [here](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Interactable.html)

However, when I apply the component to my GameObject, this component change object's default material. I want to apply to change object's color when only object is focused.

I changed 'States' of 'Interactable' that has only three stages(Focus, Press, Disabled), but this also doesn't work.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIYwt.png)
[Interactable settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU5Q8.png)

Comment: Can you include a screenshot on how your component currently looks like in the inspector?

Comment: @Kaynn Sure, I added two screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

In the state machine, an object is in one and only one state. The **Default** defines the idle state, and the object returns to this state after losing focus or releasing, it is indispensable. Depending on your needs, it is recommended that you change the color of **Default** to the color of the object material.

Besides, the main function of **States** is to setup the weights of the simultaneous multiple interaction states, it can not define which events should be listened to.